# notepad++ regex remove empty space inside/between tags and sort alphabetical order

Tags: notepad++

i use myinterest="([^"]*)" and replace with myinterest="\L\1\text" to make the text lowercase and adding "text" after, but how can i also delete unwanted space in the tag? i tried \1 but not working

EDIT: tried "find what" 
    (?:\bmyinterest="|\G)\K\h*([^"\s>]+)(\h*")?
"replace with"
    \L$1(?2text":)

this works removing space and lowercase, but how do i change so it sort per alphabetical order? i try in notepad++ but i dont get how i can sort from the words in myinterest=""

example data:

```
myinterest="footballtext">random Name</></endofothertag> 
myinterest="sportsandflowerstext">random Name</></endofothertag>
myinterest="horseridingtext">random Name</></endofothertag>
myinterest="bowlingtext">random Name</></endofothertag>
```

should be:

```
myinterest="bowlingtext">random Name</></endofothertag>
myinterest="footballtext">random Name</></endofothertag>
myinterest="horseridingtext">random Name</></endofothertag>
myinterest="sportsandflowerstext">random Name</></endofothertag>
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55207188/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: Notepad++ is not the tool to accomplish your requirements, specially the sorting. Regular Expression is a pattern matching nothing else. You can combine it with other programming languages and do what you want. Nor N++ nor Regex alone can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\bmyinterest="|\G)\K\h*([^"\s>]+)(\h*")?`
- Replace with: `\L$1(?2text":)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # non capture group
    \b              # word boundary
    myinterest="    # literally
  |                 # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
)                   # end group
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
\h*                 # 0 or more horizontal spaces
([^"\s>]+)          # group 1, 1 or more non quote space or >
(\h*")?             # group 2, 0 or more horizontal spaces and a quote, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L$1                # lowercase group 1
(?2                 # conditional replacement, if group 2 exists
    text"           # add text and quote
    :               # else, nothing
)                   # end condiitonal
```

**Given:**

```
myinterest="football"

myinterest="Sports and Flowers"

myinterest="football">random Name</></endofothertag> 
myinterest="Sports and Flowers">random Name</></endofothertag>
```

**Result for given example:**

```
myinterest="footballtext"

myinterest="sportsandflowerstext"

myinterest="footballtext">random Name</></endofothertag> 
myinterest="sportsandflowerstext">random Name</></endofothertag>
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: This is close but it also changes text in other tag, for example this is the full string: myinterest="football">randomname</></endofothertag> your regex keeps changing in the randonname etc. it should only change this part:

myinterest="football"

myinterest="Sports and Flowers"

Comment: @Tim:Don't give example i comment, it is unreadable. As I said in comment above, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55207188/372239) and add some test cases.

Comment: @Tim: Just add `>` in the character class, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot i also need to order them alphabetical order, see my updated question

Comment: @Tim: If **ALL** lines begin with `myinterest="blah blah"`, you can install plugin TextFX, see: https://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16629/notepad-7-6-and-the-plugin-textfx this plugin includes a sort utility

Comment: @Tim: In other case you can't do such operation, you have to write a small script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply example data so I improvised:

You can try this

Find what: `myinterest="\s*([^"]*?)\s*"`

Replace with: `myinterest="\L\1\Etext"`

It will transform this:

```
myinterest="   Sports and Flowers   "
myinterest="Sports and Flowers"
myinterest="SPORT and wine"
myinterest=" TV "
myinterest="   MOVIES   "
myinterest=" food    "
myinterest="   running"
myinterest="play   "
```

... into this:

```
myinterest="sports and flowerstext"
myinterest="sports and flowerstext"
myinterest="sport and winetext"
myinterest="tvtext"
myinterest="moviestext"
myinterest="foodtext"
myinterest="runningtext"
myinterest="playtext"
```

Comment: thanks but it did not work

this is my example data and how the tag is:

actually ýour regex seem to find this myinterest="fotball"> but not this one: myinterest="Sports and Flowers">

Comment: i changed the regex to be "lazy" now, it should match : myinterest="Sports and Flowers"

Comment: tried it and it finding now but not removing the empty space between words, for example myinterest="sports and flowerstext" should chjange to myinterest="sportsandflowerstext" i realize i should have mentioned this earlier :D